# Best practices for authentication/authorization in a microservices architecture

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices, roles, gateway

Where to store user roles in an architecture where the authentication service is separate from the user service?

After reading several articles, I understand that although an architecture is never perfect, it is best to have a dedicated authentication service

However, I would like to separate the authentication service from the user service, but I have gaps in the roles. Where to store the roles, in the authentication service or in the user service for best practice assuming each service has its own database?

My main concern is to avoid coupling between services as much as possible

I have placed the roles directly in the authentication service. Is this the best solution?

Comment: Roles are for authorization. So, I think you should separate them out into another service, or with the user service to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Salil, but if I separate the roles in another service (authorization or user) as you say, then how can I have the roles to integrate into the token during authentication, using JWT?

Comment: For simple apps, you can put roles in the JWT. Then you are right that roles belong to authentication server, which issues the JWT. For more complex apps, where you have multiple services and multiples roles, it may be better to just put identity info in JWT and check roles dynamically.

Comment: Keycloak is pretty popular for this task now.